# DJI SDK Waypoint Mission - UploadMission error

Tags: java, android, sdk, dji-sdk, waypoint

I'm developing an Android Application that uses the DJI SDK. The drone I'm using right now is the Mavic Pro 1. This application wants to use the predefined classes for waypoints inside the DJI SDK to create missions for the drone, but when performing the configuration of the Waypoint mission and correctly loading the mission inisde the Mission Operator (current state is set to: READY_TO_UPLOAD after calling the MissionOperator.loadMission), when trying to perform the "uploadMission" predefined function the app crashes and the Drone automatically disconects of the Application.

I think the waypoints are correctly created and saved inside the builder, otherwise it would fail in the loadMission function. Also the parameters are correct since the checkParameters function is used.

I have seen that some people in previous posts say that you need first to set the application to Ground station mode. But I don't find any indications of this existing inside the DJI SDK documentation, so I think it is deprecated and not needed anymore for current versions of the SDK.

Is the Upload of the mission inside the Operator failing because I am using a Mavic Pro 1 maybe?

If anyone has the correct steps to setup Waypoint missions or knows the error it would be of great help for all the DJI SDK users.

Best regards,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the example project for the sdk on github. It's all in there.
https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android

Mavic 1 should work with waypoints.

If you include your logcat we might help you, without that and your code, it's almost impossible to tell what you doing wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the problem was not really the uploadMission function itself, but a Toast that was trying to be shown at screen when the upload was performed. By adding the line runOnUiThread {} and the Toast inside it, is working fine. In case someone has the same problem this is the solution.